# php date timezone issue

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have PHP site which is running with some custom script. I store a last query date in the DB as UTC, like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET last_query = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id = 1";
```

When the script executes, it grabs that last date and converts it to the local tz like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT last_query FROM mytable WHERE id = 1"; // grab date
$result = $dbo->query($sql);
$row    = $result->fetch();

$last_query = new DateTime($row['last_query'], new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // build datetime

$last_query->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Denver')); // set to local tz

$last_query = $last_query->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // format

$this->log('info', "Last queried: ".$last_query);
```

In my `phpinfo()`, `date.timezone = America/Denver` but the line for `Default timezone` shows `UTC`.

I have an older logging script that prints a log line preceded by the date produced using `date`, like this: `$time = date( $this->DateFormat );`

The problem is that in the log file, it shows the last query date as incorrect:

```
2016-07-05 12:00:02 - INFO  --> Last queried: 2016-07-05T18:00:02
```

The date of the log message (`2016-07-05 12:00:02`) is correct-- the date of the `last_query` as you can see is 6hrs ahead (or UTC time).

What am I missing in my date conversion (or possibly in the PHP ini?) that is causing this mismatch? I'm assuming that I'm wrong to instantiate the `DateTime` object with the `UTC` timezone, but despite reading a lot of documentation on timezones I am still unclear.

EDIT: the `last_query` column is a mysql `TIMESTAMP` field

Comment: what's your machine's time settings look like?

Comment: What datatype is your `mytable.last_query` column?

Comment: Can you tell us what fieldtype that 'last_query' field has? Is it a TIMESTAMP? or a DATETIME? And what is actually being inserted into the field? Can you give an example value at a known timestamp?

Comment: Is this the full code? There should be some more between `$date = "SELECT last_query FROM mytable WHERE id = 1"; // grab date` and `$last_query = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // build datetime`. As it stands, you will just get a fatal error from this code.

Comment: @vascowhite-- I omitted some of the code just to keep it minimal-- the DB call returns one row and I left it out for brevity. Thanks

Comment: It may help for us to see that code.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp). It may help.